# Is there any way I can search in a file for Uptime that is greater than 100 days?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

Is there any way I can search in a file for Uptime that is greater than 100 days via Linux Bash commands?

For example, `file1` contains:

```
Uptime is 172 days

Uptime is 562 days

Uptime is 30 days

downtime is 197 days
```

What command can I use to get an output like:

```
Uptime is 172 days

Uptime is 562 days
```

Comment: This seems like a homework question.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple `awk` solution:

```bsh
awk '$1 == "Uptime" && $3 > 100 {print}' file1
```

```
Uptime is 172 days
Uptime is 562 days
```

Comment: Might be simpler as well `awk '/Uptime/ && $3 > 100' file1`

Answer (score 5):

...and a bit more complex `bash` solution:

```bsh
while read -r a b c d; do
   [[ $a = Uptime && $c -gt 100 ]] && printf '%s %s %s %s\n' $a $b $c $d
done < uptime
```

```
Uptime is 172 days
Uptime is 562 days
```

Answer (score 3):

And a `grep` solution, using Extended Regexps:

```
grep -E 'Uptime is [[:digit:]]{3}' uptime | \
  grep -Ev 'Uptime is 100'
```

This will find the "Uptime is " string, followed by at least 3 digits, and discard the exact `100` followed by End-of-line.

Comment: Better use `[[:digit:]]{3,}` (note the comma) for numbers with more than 3 digits. If leading zeros are possible, one can use `0*[1-9][0-9]{2,}` to not include those into the count.

Comment: @DavidFoerster The expression in the answer will work, because it's not anchored in any way to the end. For a line with, say, four digits, the expression will only match the first three digits, but since the expression terminates there, that will match the line. But I agree your expression is better style; it better expresses intent, and is more likely to continue working if the expression is modified.

Comment: Wouldn't this also match uptimes of 100 days, whereas the question asks for uptimes of more than 100?

Answer (score 2):

Converting from my comment.

Using `grep` and `awk` together:

```
grep "Uptime" file1 | awk '$3 > 100 {print}'
```

Look for "Uptime" in `file1` and then look at the 3rd column and print if greater than 100.